# Symfony2 TWIG show user from know ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a list of tasks stored in the doctrine database which I return like this:

```
$task = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Tasks')
    ->findAll();
return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'message' => '', 'list_tasks' => $task);
```

In one row the ID of and entry from a second table is stored. I don't want only output the ID but also the Name, Description and so on stored in the other table. With normal PHP & MYSQL this would be done by using JOIN - how can I do it with Symfony & TWIG ?

Twig Output:

```
{% for task in list_tasks%}
    {{ task.Id }}
    {{ task.TaskTitle }}
    {{ task.TaskDescription }}
    {{ task.TaskTypes }} /* Here I want not only get the ID but also other fields stored in the database with TaskType ID = task.TaskTypes */
    {{ task.User }}  /* Here I want not only get the ID but also other fields stored in the database with User ID = task.User */
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you associations set up correctly or do you just do joins of separate tables? What are the associations from task to task types (I assume manyToOne) and task to user (again I assume manyToOne)?

Comment: I didn't get it working with ManyToMany or ManyToOne ... I would be more happy when it would be solved this way...but actually its done like this:

/**
     * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\TaskTypes")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="task_type", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $TaskTypes;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="Seotool\MainBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $user;

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `TaskType` and `User` are entities, which belong within the `Tasks` entity. In which case, try the following. Note that I am getting just one task with id of 1 in my example:

```
$task = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Tasks')->find(1);
$taskTypes = $task->getTaskTypes();
$user = $task->getUser();

return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'message' => '',
    'list_tasks' => $task,
    'task_types' => $taskTypes,
    'user' => $user,
);
```

And in your Twig:

```
{% for task_type in task_types %}
    {{ task_type.Id }} // or whatever fields a task_type has
{% endfor %}
```

And the same for the `user`

Edit:

As you are wanting to have ALL tasks processed at once, I wonder if simply the following willl work:

```
{% for task_list in task_lists %}
    {% for task_type in task_list.taskType %}
        {{ task_type.Id }} // or whatever fields a task_type has
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getTaskTypes() on a non-object in /var/www/html/seotool/src/Seotool/MainBundle/Controller/TasksController.php line 75

Comment: This means that `$task` never became an object. This is likely to be that there is no Task in your database with an id of 1: `->find(1)`, try changing the id for one you know exists..

Comment: But I dont want to get just from one specific ID but from all tasks stored in the database. Using findAll() throws following exception: FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getTaskTypes() on a non-object in /var/www/html/seotool/src/Seotool/MainBundle/Controller/TasksController.php line 75

Comment: That is because in that scenario, `$task` is an array of Tasks. You will want to loop that array. Before we go further with that solution, did you try the quick possible solution at the end of my answer?

Comment: Yes I did - returns nothing. Im really confused...it's really hard to understand this all when you don't work for long time with Symfony :(
Maybe my whole structure is not good? Maybe I should do all with ManytoXXXX Fields ???

Comment: By the way: $taskTypes = $task->getTaskTypes(); returns string(2) "16"

Comment: If your data is set up correctly, I would have expected `$taskTypes` to be an array of TaskType's

Comment: Me too...But it doesn't .. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I did it now on this way, but I dont think, that it is 100% correct and conform.

How to do better? Luckily this works for me actually:

```
$task = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Tasks')
    ->findAll();

$taskTypes = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:TaskTypes')
    ->findAll();

$user = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:User')
    ->findAll();

return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'message' => '',
    'list_tasks' => $task,
    'list_task_types' => $taskTypes,
     'list_user' => $user
);
```

TWIG:

```
{% for task in list_tasks %}

    Task ID: {{ task.ID }}    <br/>

    {% for type in list_task_types if type.id == task.tasktypes %}
        {{ type.tasktypetitle }} <br/>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for user in list_user if user.id == task.user %}
        {{ user.username }} <br/>
    {% endfor %}

    <hr/>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The best way to implement this should be using `createQuiryBuilder` so that you can create a join query and fetch all required data, then just pass them to your TWIG (same as normal MySQL and PHP ;-) )